# How can I convince my company's legal department that the Python cryptography module is just a wrapper?

Tags: python, openssl, python-cryptography

I'm working for a company that builds some Python-based software.

This software gets distributed to clients globaly (that includes France and the U.S) *with its dependencies embeded*. These dependencies include the *cryptography* module.

Legal department has rightfully raised concern about crypto-related software being distributed.
However my understanding is that the *cryptography* module is built on top of cryptography backends (OpenSSL in my case). OpenSSL provides the low-level primitives (RSxxx/HSxxx encryption etc.) and *cryptography* is just a wrapper around this, not providing any encryption sofwtare itself. Is my understanding correct?

If that's the case, this might be game changer for me as libopenssl is part of the client operating environment and is NOT being distributed with the software. However legal dept is asking for evidence, and I can't find anything in *cryptography* official documentation nor in its licence that would back this claim. Any idea of how I could try to convince them?

Comment: It's open-source code. You can just go to the github page and show that it doesn't have its own cryptography code.

Comment: @Barmar good point, I've actually tried to do this. However people in legal dept are ... well lawyers and would rather be convinced by a legal disclaimer or precedents, not code.

Comment: Then I suggest you contact the maintainers of the module.

Comment: The github contains some license files: `LICENSE`, `LICENSE.APACHE`, `LICENSE.BSD`, `LICENSE.PSF`.

Comment: @Jortega none of them discuss the actual content of the module unfortunately.

Comment: *What* legal concerns? USA Cryptography export controls were removed during the Clinton administration. Your legal dept. is seriously out of date. They're the ones who need to produce evidence of a problem.

Comment: @user207421 Yes I know the U.S does not consider uploading libopenssl to a foreign country "weapon export" any more. Legal folks are actually more concerned about the opposite, i.e. importing crypto software to the U.S / France from overseas. I believe some restriction still apply in some countries.